# Is it possible to upgrade Ansible itself with the modules of Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I came across a code as;

```
- pip: name=ansible version=<ansible_version> extra_args='--ignore-installed'
```

During my test I confirmed the upgrade of Ansible version.
I also tried this with `raw` module;

```
- raw: pip install ansible==<ansible_version>
```

but the following tasks after this fails during playbook execution. There are various types of errors:

> ImportError: cannot import name AnsiblePlugin
>
> TypeError: mkdtemp() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
>
> ...

or playbook execution even hangs on next task.

I wonder is it really possible to upgrade version of Ansible by using `ansible-playbook` execution itself. Would it be possible by reloading Ansible core modules somehow after Ansible version upgrade?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: I saw this question when I was trying to determine whether an ansible host could install/maintain another item (e.g. mysql, apache etc.)  on itself. It isn't quite the same question, but I think the common issue might be things like if the task required a reboot, common dependencies.

Comment: Also I'd like to second the question from Uku Loskit [five years later] - What would be the benefit of doing this? or is it just a curiousity/interesting?

Comment: I personally don't need it.  But I've encountered such code which suddenly started to fail after my upgrade of Ansible version in a local system and I needed to explain whether my changes caused problems.  In fact, the content of the code in question was to update the Ansible version in a remote system, which then used subsequent executions in other Ansible playbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ansible` can be upgraded via `pip` module of `Ansible` itself, but any subsequent tasks might fail after the upgrade, this is a natural behavior.

Only exception is remote host here. If your installation or upgrade of `Ansible` is performed by an `Ansible` task which is executed on a remote host, it would proceed without causing a failure. Because in this scenario, actual installation of `Ansible` is done on remote host without updating any configuration of `Ansible` on localhost.